# When trying to rewrite 32 bit Python code to run on 64 bit systems, where/how do you start?

Tags: python, winapi, migration, 32bit-64bit

Working on Python code which runs fine on a 32 bit platform but then fails on a 64 bit one. There are Win32API calls in addition to ctypes in the code. How do I localize the bits of code that are only able to run on a 32bit platform? If you were trying to rewrite 32 bit code to run on a 64 bit system, where and how would you start?

Answer (score 3):

Not all 32-bit WinAPI functions work the same as their 64-bit counterparts. Also there are some APIs that have been deprecated and some of the APIs already deprecated for Win32 have been removed ( refer [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API)).

In cases where there are calls to such API( which would behave differently on 32-bit and 64-bit systems), it would help to refactor the common python logic into a separate unit (python class, module or function) - say in a module **common.py** for the sake of this discussion. All the platform specific logic should ideally be put in two separate units (one for 32-bit and the other for 64-bit) - say **platform_win32.py** and **platform_win64.py**.

The  **common.py**  file during loading can then dynamically import either of **platform_win32.py** or **platform_win64.py** based on a platform check. Once the appropriate module has been imported, **common.py** can nvoke the platform specific logic to perform it's task.

This also points to an important design principle when writing cross-platform code - NEVER directly call platform specific code within your business logic. ALWAYS wrap your platform specific logic within separate modules/classes and expose these functionalities as an API. Make sure that this API has the same signatures in both the 32-bit and 64-bit versions.Then you can conditionally import these APIs and invoke them. The beauty about this approach is that the platform check can be done during the program bootstrap and then the appropriate API loaded. Once this happens, the code calling these API will be rest-assured that the correct platform specific logic is triggered. This eliminates the need for **if platform == 'x64': else:** type checks from being interspersed through the code.

Finally, as an after thought : Use some well testes library like [PyWin32](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20218/) when dealing with core Win32 API. It already has both 32-bit and 64-bit support and then your job reduces to only shipping the correct versions of pywin32 along with your application.

Hope this helps.